# Angular and TypeScript looping through object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to learn TypeScript and Angular. I have an object that I would like to loop through and pull key:value pairs so I can create buttons dynamically in HTML. In HTML when I `<<variable>>` my object I get "[object Object]" as my output. When I do standard `ng-repeat="o in variable"` I get nothing.

My question is how do I loop through it so I can get values stored in that object.

```
HTML
    <div id="main_menu" class="container" role="main">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="page-header">WebJB</div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <button href="#" class="panel-body btn btn-primary form-control">
                <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
              </button>
          </div>


          <div ng-repeat="o in menu_parts"> <<--- I TRIED THIS
            {{menu_parts}}
          </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

TypeScript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})



export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
  menu_parts = {
    "CRM": {
      "name": "CRM",
      "link": "/",
      "colour": "white",
      "label": "CRM"
    },
    "Admin": {
      "name": "Admin",
      "link": "/admin",
      "colour": "red",
      "label": "Admin"
    },
    "Dashboard": {
      "name": "Dashboard",
      "link": "/dashboard",
      "colour": "white",
      "label": "Dashboard"
    },
    "Settings": {
      "name": "Settings",
      "link": "/settings",
      "colour": "white",
      "label": "Settings"
    }
  }



  constructor(){
    var x = this.menu_parts;
    console.log(x);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If are you using angular 2, then use `ngFor` instead of `ngRepeat`

```
<div *ngFor="let o in menu_parts"> 
     {{o}} 
 </div>
```

As for `[object object]` you have to use `json` filter to show all the content a JSON array

```
{{menu_parts | json}}
```

Comment: My version of Angular is 2.3.1

After shuffling around and reading doc for Angular it should be 
<div *ngFor="let o of menu_parts">
I also change the json structure so its less nested.
It worked at the end thanks for some tips :)

Comment: @Krzysztof Buczynski no prob